# Get Post ID in Admin Edit screen otherwise generate it?

Tags: wp-admin, save-post, id, autosave

My plugin on a special projects custom post type admin add/edit screen requires to have the post ID.

When on this CPT admin add/edit screen I would like to get the ID in PHP if it exist already.  If the post is new and does not yet have a Post ID, then I would like to save the post automatically to generate the Post ID right away.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

While clicking ADD-NEW (i mean when creating new post), it has already assigned an ID. You can catch it using javascript,like:

```
if(document.getElementById("postID")){
   alert(document.getElementById("postID"));
}
```

or catch it using PHP:

```
var_dump($GLOBALS);
```

and see the variable name